# LIKE-operator in relational algebra

Tags: sql, notation, relational-algebra

Is there a way to display a sql LIKE-operator in relational algebra?

right now I have done it like this:

> σ<sub>firstname LIKE ('B%')</sub>person

But I'm not sure if this is the right way to go.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Lets say that you using relational algebra with defined LIKE binary operation for string operands. Then your notation is valid.

Comment: To extend shibormot comment. Basically, there is no such a thing in [relational algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra). If you're making up a notation, to include that operator then that solution seems to be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [similar question covered earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875319/relational-algebra-check-for-error) on this site regarding how to use LIKE in relational algebra. In that case, the professor had indicated that it was ok to use LIKE just as in SQL.